# SAS: adding to existing macro

Tags: macros, sas

I have a macro that generates **x** datasets *test1*, *test2*, *test3*,...,*testx*, which I want to append to a dataset called *test0*. I cannot use regular proc append, because two of the columns from test0 are renamed, thus getting a different position:

Now I would like to make a macro called "set" or whatever, such that I can use it in the following merge:

```
data final;
&set.;
run;
```

,where set = "set test0 test1 ... testx"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put X into a macro variable. For example if there are 5 of them then

```
%let x=5 ;
```

Then since your tables are nicely named with numbered suffixes you can just use a range of datasets in the SET statement.  Like this:

```
data final ;
  set test0 - test&x ;
run;
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much!